# Strange message coming from Chrome debugger

Tags: jquery, debugging, google-chrome

I am debugging some jQuery code using Chrome and every few iterations of testing, this message appears in the console:

[Mon Aug 12 2013 5:32:45 PM] Solid Savings

I have googled this message and find nothing.

Comment: Do you have "Solid Savings" in your app somewhere? Are you using external libraries?

Comment: The entire message is: [Mon Aug 12 2013 7:37:46 PM] Solid Savings <Warning: appAPI.db storage is limited to 1000 bytes per key. For larger values please use appAPI.db.async Function-name: appAPI.db.set : key=_GPL_arbitrary_code>

Answer (score 0):

Its a Chrome extension. Remove it from your extensions and the error will go away.  You may want to run some anti-virus/malware on your computer.